# Is it good practice to abstract simd types?

Tags: objective-c, simd

I am writing a rendering system with Metal and I make heavy use of the simd types such as `simd_float3` and `simd_float4x4`.
Since these types are opaque and i need functions to create them such as `simd_make_float3`, i think it would make sense to encapsulate them into a separate class.
[Here is an example](https://pastebin.com/Dw4asrKn) of how I would implement it.

since the simd types are made for performance, i am not sure whether it is a good idea to actually encapsulate them in a class. I would allocate multiple vectors on the heap every time I do some calculations.

Comment: I'm no objective-C/Metal expert, but in the land of C/C++, wrapping the simd types in a class is *always* a bad idea. You are hoping that the compiler is 'good enough' to remove the extra cruft you've added, which begs the question why did you add the extra cruft to begin with? Sometimes the compiler succeeds, in many cases it won't.

Comment: Abstraction aside, vector3 is an inefficient use of SIMD. It will need painful horizontal operations, and it's limited to 3/4 capacity even with just 128bit SIMD and that ratio gets even worse as SIMD gets wider. So even if you abstract the types somehow, that shouldn't be how - maybe make a type for a bundle of 4 vec3's.

Comment: @robthebloke readability and possibility to exchange simd for something better without changing the client code. I would need to write `simd_make_float3()` everytime I want to create a vector. That's hard to read and difficult to exchange

Comment: @harold I am actually not familiar with how simd works. I was advised to use them though and since they have all functions I need like dot and cross, it looked convenient for me to use them. Am I better off using a custom implementation?

Comment: @Raildex it may be possible to do it more efficiently, but whether you'd be better off is a bit different, because it would also be less convenient. There is some discussion of this in [this talk](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022248/SIMD-at-Insomniac-Games-How)

Comment: @robthebloke I'm also no objective-C coder, but I disagree that in C/C++ it is _always_ a bad idea to wrap SIMD types. E.g., in C++ (and SSE-based SIMD) you can't distinguish between `int8x16`, `int16x8`, `int32x4`, etc. If you wrap them, you can use function (or operator) overloading on different types. Also, if you want to provide `float_8` for SSE as well as AVX, you can wrap them into either two `__m128` or one `__m256`, depending on compilation options, without having to change all code which uses it. Of course, make sure the compiler is able to optimize away any overhead.

Comment: @chtz For those who advocate wrapping your SIMD types, just be aware that you're now incompatible with a number of calling conventions.  https://godbolt.org/z/tEDYdW  Sure you *could* fix that by declaring everything as __vectorcall, but you've also forced that requirement on all users of the code. In my case it's not good enough to say 'it optimises away fine on linux + clang'. I have to deal with a number of OS/hardware/compiler combinations, and trust me (I've tried!), it is not possible to create a SIMD wrapper that optimises away in all cases. #define the intrinsics is my advice, eg add4f

Comment: Just as an example of a C++ SIMD library that doesn't wrap, see [DirectXMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath).

Comment: I did not claim that it is _always_ a good idea to wrap SIMD types (especially, I have no idea about objective-C). But if I wrap them, I would only access them with fully-inlined functions (I would consider the `foo` or `add` functions in @robthebloke's example as functions which should mostly be called from bigger functions, which work on much larger data sets). Of course, one needs to make sure that these indeed get inlined (and MSVC often does a bad job with that).

Comment: Just an example of a C++ SIMD library that doesn't wrap, and allows to compile same code into either 128 bit or 256 bit instructions, by switching C++ namespace and reusing the code: https://github.com/Const-me/IntelIntrinsics Example which compiles same source into both versions: https://github.com/Const-me/IntelIntrinsics/blob/master/CppDemo/brightness.inl https://github.com/Const-me/IntelIntrinsics/blob/master/CppDemo/brightness.cpp